# tabBar.hidden = true not hiding complete tab bar it lefts white space in bottom of view

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have 2 tab item in my tab bar controller, my requirement is to hide tab bar when user move to child screens (Other than root of each tab).

I have tried hidesBottomBarWhenPushed but some how its not working due to view hierarchy.

Also **tabBar.hidden = true** hiding the tab bar icon instead the complete tab bar. randomly it works when i scroll up down again and again the table view used on root view

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true;
```

**I am calling this line before presenting the new view in (prepare for segue method)**

On debug its seems tab bar is hidden but it left white space in bottom which remain there

**Before - Normal**
[image: With Visible Tab Bar]
**After tabBar.hidden = true**

[image: With Tab Bar Hidden]

Comment: Out of curiosity: Can you please post an image of the partly removed tabbar. Also, please show where you call `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true`. Maybe try to dispatch this line of code async to the main queue explicitly to isolate the root of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

user bellow code to hide the tabbar. for example "Tab1 and Tab2" is two tabbars, if u r moving Tab1 to inside viewcontrollerA. U can write the bellow code in "viewcontrollerA"

```
 -(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
   {
      return YES;
    }
```

Comment: where are u are calling this method?

Comment: before presenting new view

Comment: u can call after view it means. If u r moving from A to B , u can call this method in B only not A.